# Crystal Reports 8.5 Sections prevents file from being deleted in C# using COM

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I have an created a command line application which takes a crystal report file, opens it, exports it to a text file and then cleans up after itself by deleting the crystal report.  This works fine until I suppress sections in the crystal report, then when I try and delete it I get the following:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ExportCMD\bin\Debug\ReportExport\2ee373f0-e05a-42d6-9b61-9c79e2662c20\14_636271819978854269.rpt' because it is being used by another process.

After some investigation I have found that it happens when I suppress a section in the open report, if I comment out that code it works fine.  The code for setting the Suppress flag is:

```
private static void SuppressReportSection(ref Report openReport, string sectionToFind, bool hideSection)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sectionToFind) && openReport != null)
        {
            openReport.Sections[sectionToFind].Suppress = hideSection;
        }
    }
```

After checking Google for a solution, I gave the following a try:

```
private static void SuppressReportSection(ref Report openReport, string sectionToFind, bool hideSection)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sectionToFind) && openReport != null)
        {

            Sections reportSections = openReport.Sections;

            try
            {
                if (reportSections != null)
                {
                    reportSections[sectionToFind].Suppress = hideSection;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reportSections != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(reportSections);
                    reportSections = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This unfortunately didn't cure it either.  I have tried it with and without the ref in case it is something to do with the report object.

I am having to use the Crystal Reports 8.5, and I have added the reference.
When I destroy my report object I call the Marshal.ReleaseComObject, then GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() in the hope that it will have released the file.  Once all this has completed I call the cleanup code which deletes the files.  The clean up method will allow multiple attempts at deleting the file before it throws the error.

Where am I going wrong? If there is already an answer to the question can you point me to it please.

I am using C# with .Net 4 as this is the highest version we can get on the servers.  I can't use the CrystalDecisions assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use FinalReleaseComObject instead:

> Therefore, use the ReleaseComObject only if it is absolutely required. If you want to call this method to ensure that a COM component is released at a determined time, consider using the FinalReleaseComObject method instead. FinalReleaseComObject will release the underlying COM component regardless of how many times it has re-entered the CLR. The internal reference count of the RCW is incremented by one every time the COM component re-enters the CLR. Therefore, you could call the ReleaseComObject method in a loop until the value returned is zero. This achieves the same result as the FinalReleaseComObject method.

[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's all still in your task manager all you have to do is..

Just remove the file in `task manager` using task kill by opening a `.bat file`. You can do this after you execute or before deleting the report.. after this you are freely can delete the file or you can open it again without any error.